# Update table column that is used for ordering according to alphabetical order on a second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have two tables (A and B) that have a relation of n-n.

So there is a third table (C) that is used to connect both tables.

Table A and B both have an Id and a name.

Table C has IDA, IDB and an Order, the number that is used to sort and that is user given.

My issue is that I need to migrate table C since I just added that order column and so I need to give every line an ordering number, according to the B name.

So if table A has:

```
Id Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

And Table B has:

```
Id Name
1  J
2  L
3  M
```

And table C has:

```
IdA  IdB  Order
1    2    0
1    1    0
1    3    0
2    1    0
2    3    0
```

I need a query that updates table C to be more like:

```
IdA  IdB  Order
1    2    2
1    1    1
1    3    3
2    1    1
2    3    2
```

I have a query that can basically do what i want but it leaves me with "gaps"
reading my results above i get:

```
IdA  IdB  Order
1    2    2
1    1    1
1    3    3
2    1    1
2    3    3
```

Comment: Don't tag spam irrelevant products.  Only tag the DBMS you're *actually* using.

Comment: Also, your question is unclear - is the `Order` column *always* equal to `B`?

Comment: How did you get those results? Order for Table C is based off what? If it's just the same value of B then set col3 = col2...

Comment: sorry about the tag spam :)

Comment: What is your DBMS?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?  Something else?

Comment: i'm using postgreSQL,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for what you need:

```
With ToUpdate As
(
    Select  C.*,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By C.IdA Order By B.Name) As NewOrder
    From    C
    Join    B   On  B.Id = C.IdB
)
Update  C
Set     "Order" = U.NewOrder
From    ToUpdate    U
Where   U.IdA = C.IdA 
And     U.IdB = C.IdB
```

(In full disclosure, I'm not terribly familiar with postgres, but I *think* this should be valid).

Comment: Your solution gets me closer, but that doesn't work in postgresql.The select part inside with() gives me a good ordering but then the call to update gives an error

Comment: @w84m3 I was afraid of that - what is the error message?

Comment: the relation ToUpdate doesn't exist

Comment: @w84m3 Updated the query - try using this instead.